# Is there an elegant way to write nested if statements in R?

Tags: r, if-statement, tidyverse, purrr

Is there a more elegant way to write nested `if` statements in R?

```r
cond1 <- T 
cond2 <- F
cond3 <- T

if (cond1)
  if(cond2)
    if(cond3)
      x <- 1
```

Consider that a condition must only be evaluated if the previous one is `TRUE` (in the case that it takes time to get `cond2`, `cond3`, etc)

I want something similar to the following code:

```r
x <- multiple_if(1, cond1, cond2, cond3)
```

I know the `purrr::when` function, but it does not satisfy my needs.

Comment: `if(cond1 && cond2 && cond3)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the following code solves the question's problem. It uses `mget` to put the logical variables in a list to be passed to `Reduce`.

```r
cond1 <- TRUE
cond2 <- FALSE
cond3 <- TRUE

l <- mget(ls(pattern = "^cond"))
l
#> $cond1
#> [1] TRUE
#> 
#> $cond2
#> [1] FALSE
#> 
#> $cond3
#> [1] TRUE

Reduce(`&&`, l)
#> [1] FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-02 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: `&&` seems to meet what I need

Comment: `purrr::when(isTRUE(Reduce(`&&`, l)) ~ 1, ~ NULL)` would complete your code

Comment: or `all(unlist(l))`

Comment: @moodymudskipper Much simpler, thanks.

Comment: `all(unlist(l))` tests all conditions, so it's slower than `Reduce(`&&`, l)`

Answer (score 0):

Don't overlook the very useful `all()` and `any()` functions in base r.

```
x <- all(cond1, cond2, cond3)   # returns TRUE if ALL conditions are TRUE

x <- any(cond1, cond2, cond3)   # returns TRUE if ANY condition is TRUE
```

Comment: `all` is slower than `&&` since it tests all the conditions

Comment: `all(F, {Sys.sleep(5); T}); F && {Sys.sleep(3); T}`

Comment: it may be slower, but it adds clarity to the code, can be used across rows or columns, and works reliably within complex magrittr/tidyverse data frame manipulations.    The time difference is not material with the mid-sized datasets (5k rows, 100 cols) we work with.